# access my client's VPN from my own computer?

Tags: vpn

I can access the network of my client through a computer he has lent to me, a USB key and a pin.

I am a nomad and prefer not to  carry 2 computers: my own and my client's one.

is there a software that I can install on my own computer so that that I can access my client's vpn ( without asking it to my client's admin ?  )

Answer (score 0):

If they give you a computer it's probably because that one has a specific VPN configuration that it's pointing to the VPN server and its whitelisted, if it's really that much of an inconvenience you should talk to your client.

Also without more data it's hard to say

Comment: Are there specific data that I can collect from the computer and share here for help ?